# database.com force.com and salesforce.com

Tags: database, salesforce, force.com

I am currently trying to learn salesforce.

Following is my understanding(*correct me if i am wrong*)

**Database.com**

- Database as a service.
- Uses oracle under the hood.
- Provides REST API service to interact with database.

**Force.com**

- Platform as a service.
- Provides metadata layer(Apex language,tool to edit/debug code,visualforce page etc.)
- Provides default metadata for database.com field types.
- Uses Database.com under the hood(for storing data and metadata).

**Salesforce.com**

- Software as a service.
- Uses Force.com under the hood.
- Provides few data model (i.e.schema) eg:-sales,marketing.
- Provides a framework(mainly UI) to create/configure various parameters of metadata and data model.

**Question**

I believe database.com, force.com and salesforce.com are 3  different services.
But on searching I am always reaching to salesforce CRM.Is it possible to use Database.com or Force.com alone i.e. without salesforce CRM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the database is currently going by the name of **[Force.com Database](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Database)**, while **[database.com](http://database.force.com/)** is the name of one of the salesforce editions (products). I haven't heard much about database.com recently, and most of the links to database.com seem to be redirected, so it seems like they are trying to phase it out.

As for the underlying database technologies that support salesforce, Oracle seems to be the main one, [link](https://www.zdnet.com/article/salesforces-oracle-database-dependence-can-it-open-source-its-way-out/), [link](https://gigaom.com/2014/01/08/benioff-were-still-an-oracle-but-not-just-an-oracle-shop/). But when working with the force.com database, it's very different from Oracle, and the SOQL language is very different from SQL (e.g. no JOIN).

Your description of force.com and salesforce.com seems basically correct.

As for using them separately, you can essentially build a web app to do whatever you want on the force.com platform. That being said, the ecosystem mostly revolves around the CRM products (sales/service cloud, marketing cloud). Besides CRM customers developing/customizing the systems for their own use, the platform also draws ISVs who publish their apps on the appexchange to sell to salesforce.com CRM customers.